# How can I bring a raster into R using a previously defined year in the name

Tags: r, raster

This seems like A simple question but I'm not sure how to phrase it or ask.
I want to bring in to r many rasters from many years and instead of typing them all out, I want to be able to define the year and bring in rasters by incorporating that defined year. This way I can copy and paste my code and instead of changing the year in every raster name, I can just change it once where I define the year.

Here is an example. I defined year as 2012 and in r.12 I tried using it to bring in the raster but this didn't work. r.1 is an example of how the rasters are all named.

```
year <- 2012

r.12 <- raster("pr_total_mm_CRU_TS40_historical_12_",year,".tif")
r.1 <- raster("pr_total_mm_CRU_TS40_historical_01_2012.tif")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `r.12 <- raster(paste0("pr_total_mm_CRU_TS40_historical_12_",year,".tif"))`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!